# Linked List Push Front Not working Correctly

Tags: c++, linked-list

This is the part giving me trouble. In my diagram I'm pointing p to head and then setting my new head to p but its not working out in real life. Any suggestions?

```
{
                        // p points to a new node
    Node *p = new Node( s,0);

if( head == 0 )         // head not pointing to a node yet?
{
    head = tail = p;    // head & tail point to new node in the list
}
else
{                       // head->next points to new node
    head       = p-> get_next();
    head = p;


            // head points to first node in the list
}
```

Here's is the `get_next()` function.

```
Node *Node::get_next( ) const   // get a Node * (value of next)
{
return next;                //returns current objects pointer to next
}
```

I tried looking at some of the previous cases I'v seen online and I'm starting to wonder if my `get_next()` is wrong. Unfortunately I have to use it for this assignment.

Comment: you're overwriting head with p as soon as you set it to p->next

Comment: in else part u have wrriten a comment like this // head->next points to new node, but are assigning p->next to head and not head->next =p

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please! And yes I'm a code nazi, if anyone has doubts about that!

Comment: @MonisMajeed He's attempting to push_front, so he actually wants to assign the original address of head to p->next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to assign to p->next directly (as in LIJIN C 's answer) or use a set_next(Node*) function. get_next() only returns the *value* of p->next (i.e. the address of a Node object), it doesn't allow you to modify it, which is what you are trying to do.

A set_next function would look something like this:

```
// Returned pointer is just for convenience, this could easily be void
Node* Node::set_next(Node* newNext)
{
    return p->next = newNext;
}
```

Your else block then becomes:

```
else
{   
    // p->next points to head
    p.set_next(head);
    head = p;
    // head points to first node in the list
}
```

Edit: One more thing. The way your code is currently written (i.e. as a singly linked list that can only be traversed in one direction) you don't need a tail pointer. Even if you plan to `pop_back()`, you still have to traverse the entire list to find the new `tail`. `head` is all you need.

Comment: It worked but I'm a little confused. Why did putting head in the ()  make it work? Thanks, btw

Comment: @user3743209 `head` is a Node*--the location of a Node object in memory--just like `p` and like `p->next`, right? Passing `head` to the function allows `p` to assign the value of `head` to its `next` member.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

p->next =head;

head=p;

Ie make the newly created node's next as head and change head to newly created node